# C++ custom memory manager error when deleting objects

Tags: c++, memory-management

there.

I'm developing a custom virtual machine, and I'm using custom memory managed classes (every object will reside in one big block of memory that the virtual machine will manage).

The problem is: valgrind gives me "Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line" error when trying to delete one of these objects and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance.

**The valgrind error:**

```
[Stub] static void CeliVM::MemoryManagedClass::operator delete(pointer) in /home/patrick/Projects/CeliVM/Source/Memory.cxx @ 507
==4812== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==4812==    at 0x310040529CBA0040: ???
==4812==    by 0x401CA2: main (Main.cxx:89)
==4812==  Address 0x310040529cba0040 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4812==
```

**The delete operator:**

```
void MemoryManagedClass::operator delete ( pointer objectPointer ) noexcept
{
    MemoryAllocator* memoryAllocator = static_cast<MemoryManagedClass*>( objectPointer )->memoryAllocator;
    memoryAllocator->Free( DATA( objectPointer ) );
}
```

**The memory allocator "Free" method:**

```
void BasicMemoryAllocator::Free( data dataBlock )
{
    // Find the allocated block on the list.

    u64 allocatedBlockIndex = Kernel.Any;

    for ( u64 blockIndex = 0; blockIndex < this->numberOfAllocatedBlocks; blockIndex++ )
        if ( this->allocatedBlocks[ blockIndex ].block == dataBlock )
        {
            allocatedBlockIndex = blockIndex;
            break;
        }

    if ( allocatedBlockIndex == Kernel.Any )
    {
        ERROR( Txt::CouldNotFindRequestedAllocatedBlock, intpointer( dataBlock ) );
        return;
    }

    // Check if we have an adjacent free block we can expand or we need to create a new one.

    u64 freeBlockIndex = Kernel.Any;

    for ( u64 blockIndex = 0; blockIndex < this->numberOfFreeBlocks; blockIndex++ )
        if ( ( this->freeBlocks[ blockIndex ].start == this->allocatedBlocks[ allocatedBlockIndex ].end + 1 ) ||
             ( this->freeBlocks[ blockIndex ].end == this->allocatedBlocks[ allocatedBlockIndex ].start - 1 ) )
        {
            freeBlockIndex = blockIndex;
            break;
        }

    if ( freeBlockIndex == Kernel.Any )
    {
        // If we do not have more "free blocks" to use, we must expand the free blocks list.

        if ( this->numberOfFreeBlocks == this->freeBlocksCapacity )
        {
            BlockInfo* newFreeBlocks = new (std::nothrow) BlockInfo[ this->freeBlocksCapacity + BasicMemoryAllocator::BlocksCapacityIncrement ];

            if ( !newFreeBlocks )
            {
                ERROR( Txt::CouldNotExpandFreeBlocksList );
                return;
            }

            memcpy( newFreeBlocks, this->freeBlocks, this->freeBlocksCapacity * sizeof( BlockInfo ) );

            delete [] this->freeBlocks;
            this->freeBlocks = newFreeBlocks;
            this->freeBlocksCapacity += BasicMemoryAllocator::BlocksCapacityIncrement;

            DEBUG( Dbg::FreeBlocksListExpanded, this->freeBlocksCapacity );
        }

        memcpy( &this->freeBlocks[ this->numberOfFreeBlocks++ ], &this->allocatedBlocks[ allocatedBlockIndex ], sizeof( BlockInfo ) );
    }
    else
        {
            // Join the freed block to the adjacent free block.

            this->freeBlocks[ freeBlockIndex ].size += this->allocatedBlocks[ allocatedBlockIndex ].size;

            if ( this->freeBlocks[ freeBlockIndex ].start == this->allocatedBlocks[ allocatedBlockIndex ].end + 1 )
                this->freeBlocks[ freeBlockIndex ].start = this->allocatedBlocks[ allocatedBlockIndex ].start;
            else
                this->freeBlocks[ freeBlockIndex ].end = this->allocatedBlocks[ allocatedBlockIndex ].end;
        }


    // Remove the allocated block from the allocated blocks list.

    u64 blockStart = this->allocatedBlocks[ allocatedBlockIndex ].start;
    u64 blockEnd = this->allocatedBlocks[ allocatedBlockIndex ].end;

    this->numberOfAllocatedBlocks--;

    if ( allocatedBlockIndex < this->numberOfAllocatedBlocks )
        memcpy( &this->allocatedBlocks[ allocatedBlockIndex ], &this->allocatedBlocks[ this->numberOfAllocatedBlocks ], sizeof( BlockInfo ) );

    DEBUG( Dbg::BlockFreed, blockStart, blockEnd );
}
```

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended. `operator delete` runs after the destructor; the now-dead object's member variables are gone, including one named `memoryAllocator`.

Comment: Interesting, but this is the only MemoryManagedClass descendant that behaves like this, the other classes work fine. In my understanding, as the memoryAllocator is not destroyed when the class is destroyed, it's still on the same memory location as it's always been, and since I'm managing the memory block I should have no reason to not be able to access it. But anyhow, thanks, maybe I will use global allocators instead.

Comment: Does this one problematic descendant (let's call it `D`) have other base classes? A virtual base class perhaps? My guess is, you have trouble with it because `MemoryManagedClass` sub-object is not at offset 0 within the instance of `D`, and so `static_cast<MemoryManagedClass*>( objectPointer )` gives you a wrong address. Effectively, you are doing `reinterpret_cast<MemoryManagedClass*>(static_cast<D*>(objectPointer))`, which exhibits undefined behavior (for a different reason), but would appear to work as long as `MemoryManagedClass` just happens to be located at offset 0 inside `D`.

Comment: Well, `D` does not have any other base classes, and I'm not sure why it did not work, but, as I answered below, I managed to get around it by saving the address of the memory allocator before the object. It's not the best solution, but does the job for now. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Found it: the problematic class `D` has a virtual destructor (it's meant to be extended), but I forgot to include a virtual destructor in MemoryManagedClass (the `D` base class). I think you were right about the wrong offset. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

The problematic class has a virtual destructor, but the base class did not have. Adding a virtual destructor to the base class seems to solve the problem.

---

Well, allocating an extra int64 before the object and saving the memory allocator address there seemed to solve the problem: when deleting the object the address of the memory allocator used to allocate the object can be found before it in memory.

**new:**

```
pointer MemoryManagedClass::operator new ( size_t dataSize, MemoryAllocator* memoryAllocator ) noexcept
{
    pointer objectAddress = memoryAllocator->Get( dataSize + sizeof( i64 ) );

    if ( !objectAddress )
        return NULL;

    static_cast<MemoryManagedClass*>( objectAddress )->memoryAllocator = memoryAllocator;

    i64 allocatorAddress = intpointer( memoryAllocator );
    memcpy( objectAddress, &allocatorAddress, sizeof( i64 ) );

    return DATA( objectAddress ) + sizeof( i64 );
}
```

**delete:**

```
void MemoryManagedClass::operator delete ( pointer objectPointer ) noexcept
{
    i64 allocatorAddress = *reinterpret_cast<i64*>( DATA( objectPointer ) - sizeof( i64 ) );
    MemoryAllocator* memoryAllocator = reinterpret_cast<MemoryAllocator*>( allocatorAddress );

    memoryAllocator->Free( DATA( objectPointer ) - sizeof( i64 ) );
}
```